# How to keep content contained inside <div/>?

Tags: html, css

I have an object property,`block.content`, like the following that I want to display inside `<div/>`, but the `<p>` is sticking out when the texts are properly contained inside the `<div/>`:

```
var block = {
"content": `<a href=\"http:\/\
               /twitter.com\/ngun\" target=\"_blank\">@ngun<\/a> `
};
```

How can I get the `block.content` to contain inside the `<div>`?

Comment: When you say the image is 'sticking out' do you mean that its not visually contained by the card? If so, I'd examine the CSS that is applied to the card. Its possible that it has a fixed height, with no overflow rules.

Comment: @MichaelCamden Yes, visually the image is partly outside of the card when I want it to be contained inside the card. I did check but couldn't not find any clues. If you have a chance and find it, please let me know so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because the img tag inside your card can be set to an image of any size, you'll need to constrain its maximum size so that it fits inside your card. For example, if your cards are 300x300 pixels, but the image can be 1000x1000, you'd need that img tag to be resized down to match the size of its HTML container (the DIV) rather than the image itself.  To do this, you'll need to apply a CSS class on the container element of your dynamic content.

In CSS:

```
.dynamic-content-div img {
  /* Set width of image to maximum width of Card, height will follow aspect ratio */
  width: 100%;
}
```

JSX:

```
var block = {
  "content": `<p><img src=\"http:\/\/media.tumblr.com\
               /tumblr_lh6x8d7LBB1qa6gy3.jpg\"\/><a href=\"http:\/\
               /citriccomics.com\/blog\/?p=487\" target=\"_blank\">TO READ
               THE REST CLICK HERE<\/a><br\/>\n\nMilky Dog was inspired by
               something <a href=\"http:\/\/gunadie.com\/naomi\"
               target=\"_blank\">Naomi Gee<\/a> wrote on twitter, I really
               liked the hash tag <a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/
               search?q=%23MILKYDOG\" target=\"_blank\">#milkydog<\/a>
               and quickly came up with a little comic about it. You can
               (and should) follow Naomi on twitter <a href=\"http:\/\
               /twitter.com\/ngun\" target=\"_blank\">@ngun<\/a> `
};

return (
  <Card style={{ width: 200, height: 300, overflow: 'auto' }}>
    <CardText>
      <div className="dynamic-content-div" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: block.content }}/>
    </CardText>
  </Card>
);
```

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4wm2drpt/

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as props to the component:

```
class Foo extends React.Component{ 
  render() {

    return (
      <Card>
        <CardText>
          <div> {this.props.content} </div>
        </CardText>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
<Foo content={{content}} />
```

Or if you wish to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you can try:

```
class Foo extends React.Component{ 
  render() {

    return (
      <Card>
        <CardText>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content}}/>
        </CardText>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
<Foo content={{content}} />
```

Comment: Sorry but could you show how it would work with the example I provided, with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: block.content}}` for clarification?

Comment: I've updated the answer, but what is the purpose of using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? I wouldn't recommend to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You are actually doing this fine but your content is missing an ending p tag. `</p>` which is likely throwing off your HTML structure.

Comment: The `<p>` tag's closing tag is optional or not needed under a whole list of rules; not necessarily required.